# Setting Up JUnit 4 on VScode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, junit

I have a below simple file structure in which I have jar files of JUnit 4:

```
->Wipro
  ->Sum.java
  ->testSum.java
  ->junit-4.13.jar
  ->hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

I have tested and ran the tests successfully manually on the command line using below command:

```
javac -cp .:junit-4.12.jar testSum.java
java -cp .:junit-4.13.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore testSum
```

Now I want to accomplish this using VScode. Truly speaking, every docs or websites tells how to use test runner but no one specifies how to set it up. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60961140/how-i-can-install-junit-5-on-vscode) for setting up JUnit 5, so I tried to do the following thing as mentioned in above question:

```
"java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "$home/Documents/Wipro/junit-4.13.jar",
        "$home/Documents/Wipro/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"
    ]
```

But above thing doesn't work as I don't see any tests on the Test Palette of VSCode. Also codelens on individual testcases is not visible.

Please help me to setup JUnit 4 on VScode.

Thank You!

**EDIT**
I am not using Maven or Gradle. I want JUnit to run independently.

Answer (score 0):

In case I get no answers for Junit 4, I must post here that I had to move to version 5 of JUnit to get it working. So the link that I have provided in the question provides the correct way to setup JUnit 5 in vscode. So I will wait for an answer on JUnit4.